# How do I enable Thymeleaf auto-reload with a custom resolver in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I had to define a template resolver to get a custom dialect working, however this broke the auto-reloading of Thymeleaf templates. How can I re-enable this functionality? Alternatively, how do I add a custom dialect without having to define a template resolver?

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TagCacheService tagCacheService) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver primaryResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        primaryResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        primaryResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        primaryResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        primaryResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        primaryResolver.setOrder(0);
        primaryResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(primaryResolver);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new MyDialect(tagCacheService));
        return templateEngine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the source code of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration` and I see that other dialects there are registered by just declaring an instance of the dialect as a bean. So maybe try that?

```
@Bean
public MyDialect myDialect(TagCacheService tagCacheService) {
  return new MyDialect(tagCacheService);
}
```

Comment: Doing it like this didn't work for me for some reason but I figured it out. There is a ```setCacheable(bool)``` method on the resolver that, when set to false, enables autoreloading.

Answer (score 0):

To enable auto-reloading of templates on a custom template resolver, the set `setCacheable` property of the resolver to false. You can read this value from application properties to make it more versatile.

```
// Get value from config
@Value("${spring.thymeleaf.cache}")
private boolean enableCache;

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver primaryResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    [ ... ]
    primaryResolver.setCacheable(enableCache); // Set to false to enable reloading
    [ ... ]
}
```